# name 'cPickle' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, pickle, nameerror

I am trying to run a code on colab given below:

```
vocab_file = 'vocabs/vocab_train.pkl'
vocab = utils.load_variables(vocab_file)
```

it calls a function **load_variables**

***and here's a file of that function calling***

```
import pickle as cPickle

def load_variables(pickle_file_name):
  if os.path.exists(pickle_file_name):
    with open(pickle_file_name, 'rb') as f:
      d = cPickle.load(f)
    return d
```

here's the error it is throwing

[image]

I tried changing it to "**import pickle/import cPickle**" as well but it keeps on showing same error.

Comment: It doesn't exist in Python 3. That's the default version now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd be aliasing it as 'cPickle' but your traceback doesn't match your code

Comment: even after writing "import pickle" and changing name everywhere, it still gives me an error "NameError: name 'cPickle' is not defined"

Comment: Is the interpreter actually pointing to 2.7, without you realising it?

Comment: Yes you're right. I am using caffe and it was pointing to 2.7

Comment: @Imaq_fq Is the issue fixed now because of that?

Comment: @Hcaertnit yes it doesn't give error on that part now

Answer (score 0):

`cPickle` was replaced by `pickle` in Python 3.  You're likely using a Python 2.7 interpreter instead of a Python 3 one.